# 150ms delay in performing a HTTPS versus HTTP get request in Node

Tags: node.js, https, delay

I don't know much about how the https module in node.js works so if any of you can answer this question then that would be great.

I have noticed in a small app I made that it takes about ~150ms for a HTTPS.get(...) function to execute from scratch before any actual request is sent out. This is what im talking about:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

console.time("Begin");

function request() {
    console.timeEnd("Begin");
    var myvar = https.get("https://www.fiadkbjadfklblnfthiswebsidedoesnotexist.com", function(res) {
        });
    console.timeEnd("Begin");
    }

request();
```

When I use 'https.get', the console says that approximately 150ms passed before the code even starts doing anything with the get request. However when I use 'http.get' the delay is less than <5ms.

My question is, what exactly is causing this 150ms delay and is there anyway to reduce it?  Im sure that it is not ssl handshaking because this delay happens even when I input a non-existant website. It would be great if it was possible to code something earlier in the program so that when I execute a https.get() request, it would not have such a long startup time.

Comment: It would help us out to use less psuedo-code in your question when the issue could certainly be related to your code.

Comment: Are you confused because your server is taking `150ms` to respond, or because your app is making a request to another server and that is taking `150ms`?

Comment: @BrendanAshworth here I made a simple piece of code that demonstrates what I want to know. I want to know why their is a 150ms lapse between the two timeEnd's verser less than 5ms when using http.get

Comment: @loganfsmyth I think its the first thing you mentioned and I think I have an idea of what I need to do. Correct me if im wrong, but I should setup the server with all the certificates and encoding earlier in the code so it doesn't have to do all that work at the time I call https.get()?

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense, you aren't timing the actual HTTPS request, you're timing the launch of it - put your `console.timeEnd()` INSIDE the `https.get` callback.

Comment: @BrendanAshworth Im not trying to time the HTTPS request aka the "ping". I am trying to time how long it takes to actually perform the request, whether it is successful or not. As it is now, the second Timeend returns "Begin: 150ms" however, when I replace https with http it says "Begin: 4ms".

Comment: @JonathanGordon assuming you mean without the response, SSL latency can be a [big issue](http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/ssl-latency.html).

Comment: @BrendanAshworth Ok, so that 150ms startup time is the https making the initial handshake? But why is it that even if you put absolutely nothing where the url should go it still takes 150ms? My goal, if possible, is to perform whatever is taking that 150ms earlier in the code so I can call an https request with little delay.

Comment: @JonathanGordon when I test it on my machine I get 21ms, when the website doesn't exist, 2ms. Something must be wrong with your implementation. `node --version` ?

Comment: @BrendanAshworth I am using the same version. After a little more digging in the source code and some process monitor logs, I'm pretty sure that there is something going on with crypto. Even if it is not, I figured it would be easier to just re-write my code so it pre-establishes a connection to the host instead of spending any more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `console.timeEnd('Begin')` multiple times in your code

> As of node v6.0.0, timeEnd() deletes the timer to avoid leaking it

So when you call `console.timeEnd('Begin')` first, it deletes the timer & on second call of `console.timeEnd('Begin')` it can not find the reference to same

You can create multiple labels if you want 2 timers for different issues, but make sure you just write `timeEnd()` only once for every `time()`