# What is the meaning of this??? Vanilla Node.js I/O blockage clears up when I use strongloop controller API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, blocking, strongloop

Earlier I asked a question about what was causing a particular delay in node.js:
[150ms delay in performing a HTTPS versus HTTP get request in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372129/150ms-delay-in-performing-a-https-versus-http-get-request-in-node?lq=1)

Unsatisfied with some of the answers I received, I decided to try to figure it out myself. I came across StrongLoop api server and decided to try it out just by chance. The result was that it fixed the delay! But I do not have any clue why and what is going on! I would like to know what could possibly be causing this blockage in vanilla node, and why running strongloop fixes it.

Here is my test code:

```
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http')

console.time("Stage1");
console.time("Stage2");
console.time("Response");
console.time("End");

var options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    method: 'GET'
    }

function request() {
    console.timeEnd("Stage1");

    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            buffer =+ chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            console.timeEnd("End");
        });
    }).on('response', function () {
        console.timeEnd("Response");
    });

    console.timeEnd("Stage2");

    req.end();
}
request();
```

This is what it looks like when I run it in vanilla node.js:

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop>node test
Stage1: 0ms
Stage2: 148ms
Response: 425ms
End: 537ms
```

And this is what it looks like running in SLC:

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop>slc run test
INFO strong-agent not profiling, StrongOps configuration not found.
Generate configuration with:
    npm install -g strongloop
    slc strongops
See http://docs.strongloop.com/strong-agent for more information.
supervisor running without clustering (unsupervised)
Stage1: 0ms
Stage2: 10ms
Response: 274ms
End: 387ms
```

What is going on??? Why does vanilla node take an additional 100+ ms to perform the `https.response()` function? What is causing this blockage?

PS. I am somewhat confident that it is within the node.js core as Process Monitor shows no file or network reads causing this significant of a delay.

EDIT: Additional Info:
Yes, I am using the latest version of node, and I have ran this code dozens of times with similar results on both a local machine and an online VPS.

Comment: What's the node version?  Have you tried it with the latest 0.11.x?

Comment: @generalhenry No, I have not tried it on any beta versions.

Comment: On linux I'm simply not seeing the bug (148ms is clearly a bug) I suspect the strongloop build of node contains a fix and slc is running their version. Most likely the unstable branch (0.11.x) contains the same fix. 0.12.x should be out soon.

Comment: @generalhenry GAHHH! What have you done! Installing 0.11.14 not only made it worse but now SLC has the bug as well! Looks like Im going back to 0.10.33. Perhaps it is because I am on a windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect measurement error. You are one-shoting a call to google. How long that will take is going to vary a lot. I'd suggest running in a loop dozens to hundreds of times to get a better sense of variation.

My run of your code (on linux):

`sam@samtu:/tmp % node _.js
Stage1: 0ms
Stage2: 29ms
Response: 290ms
End: 293ms
sam@samtu:/tmp % slc run _.js
INFO strong-agent not profiling, StrongOps configuration not found.
supervisor running without clustering (unsupervised)
Stage1: 0ms
Stage2: 11ms
Response: 299ms
End: 301ms`

Btw, I think you mean "buffer += chunk;" (but you don't define buffer anywhere).

For the record, we (I'm one of the slc authors) don't have a custom build of node, we just run node. Also, the only sls crun code that is running is enough to see that you don't want clustering, and don't have a strongloop.json file, so we aren't going to cluster and aren't going to load our compiled addon... so we do nothing but start your app. This smells like a problem with your system, but you don't describe node version, or system, or how you installed node, or what systems you reproed on. Its clearly not some kind of universal problem (you can see my run above, node 0.10.32, ubuntu 14.10).

I suggest the relationship with slc is illusory. If your test file is test.js, try running this in the same directory:

```
require('module')._load(
  require('path').resolve('test.js'),
  null, true);
```

Which is effectively what slc run does.

Comment: I can run these pieces of code dozens upon dozens of times with the same result each time! As a matter of fact, you don't even need to actually send a successful request. The blockage is occurring when compiling and executing the function, before it ever sends out anything over the network.